# When should I decrement a variable inside of a bracket and when should I do it outside?

Tags: c++, sorting, insertion, decrement

I was implementing a version of insertion sort when I noticed my function did not work properly if implemented the following way. This version is supposed to sort the elements as they are copied into a new array while keeping the original intact.

```
vector<int> insertionSort(vector<int>& heights) {
    vector<int> expected(heights.size(), 0);
    int j, key;
    for(int i = 0; i < expected.size(); i++){
        expected[i] = heights[i];
        
        j = i-1;
        key = expected[i];
        while(j >= 0 && expected[j] > key){
            expected[j+1] = expected[j--];    
        }
        
        expected[j+1] = key;
        
    }
    
    return expected;
}
```

I noticed that when doing expected[j--] the function does not work as it should but when I decrement outside of the bracket it works fine.
In other words, what is the difference between

```
while(j >= 0 && expected[j] > key){
    expected[j+1] = expected[j--];    
}
```

and

```
while(j >= 0 && expected[j] > key){
    expected[j+1] = expected[j];
    --j;
}
```

Comment: Start with the simplest code. Not only is it easier on humans, it's more likely to be correct and a good compiler, written by humans at least for the foreseeable future, will also more easily infer the intent and optimize better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer this, we need to take a look at what order the arguments to `expected[j+1] = expected[j--];` are evaluated in. Looking at cppreference's page on [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), we see the following applies for C++17 and newer:

> 20. In every simple assignment expression `E1 = E2` and every compound assignment expression `E1 @= E2`, every value computation and side effect of `E2` is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of `E1`

In your case, this means that every value computation *and side effect* of `expected[j--]` is computed before it begins evaluating `expected[j+1]`. In particular, that means that `j+1` will be based on the value `j` has *after* you've decremented it with `j--`, not the value it had before.

---

Prior to C++17, it was indeterminate whether the left hand side or the right hand side of the assignment operation was sequenced first. This means that in C++14 and earlier, your code exhibits undefined behavior:

> 2. If a side effect on a memory location is unsequenced relative to a value computation using the value of any object in the same memory location, the behavior is undefined.

In this case "a memory location" is `j` and the decrement in `j--` is unsequenced relative to the value computation `j+1`. This is very similar to cppreference's example of undefined behavior:

> `a[i] = i++;       // undefined behavior until C++17`

---

In the second version of your code, the decrement to `j` does not take place until after the assignment has been completed.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was very clear and helped me understand why I could not reproduce this problem in some online compilers.